# Running process that feeds on pipe STDOUT is untrackable until something is fed to pipe STDIN

Tags: java, linux, bash, pipe

I'm trying to implement named PIPE based inter-process communication between a running java program and console. Contents of java program (Test.java) are:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // starts pipe server
        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
        boolean shutdown = false;
        while(!shutdown) {
            String inputStr = bufReader.readLine();
            if(inputStr != null) {
                System.out.println("PONG: "+inputStr);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Program was compiled using:

```
javac Test.java
```

A named pipe was created:

```
mkfifo testing
```

Then program was ran as consumer of pipe STDOUT:

```
java Test < testing
```

Then, using console, I'm sending a ping to pipe STDIN:

```
echo PING > testing
```

Which is captured by java program, outputting:

```
PONG: PING
```

**Now the strange issue**: whenever java program is ran, *until a message is sent to pipe*, its process is untrackable using *ps eaux* or even in */proc/*.

This reproduces both on ubuntu (work computer) and rhel (production server) OS. Does anyone have any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has nothing to do with your java program, but with the shell you're starting it from, and with the behavior of named pipes.

In a command like `program <file`, the shell will first `fork()` a separate process, then perform the redirection by `open()`ing `file`, and finally `execve()` the `program`.

If the `file` is a named pipe/fifo, `open()`ing it will block until its other end is opened too. Thence the behavior you're observing, where your java program isn't started until you `open()` the other end of the fifo.

You can easily work around that by opening the fifo in read/write mode, which will not block, but that means giving up on the ability to detect when the reader has closed its end of the pipe -- your program will never get an `EOF` on its stdin:

```
mkfifo testing
java Test 0<>testing
```

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate it is not Java related.

Here the same code implemented in Shell:

```sh
shutdown=1
while [ $shutdown -ne 0 ]; do
  read -r inputStr
  if [ -n "$inputStr" ]; then
    echo "PONG: ${inputStr}"
  fi
  sleep 1.000s
done
```

```
sh Test.sh < testing
```